# "Close out" or just "close"

Tags: phrase-requests

What is the difference between "close out" & just "close"? I was writing a report to my client that everything has been done and I'm closing/closing out the task/ticket now. What should be the correct word & why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either one would work, but I prefer "close out" here. It's usually used in a more intangible sense of finishing something, compared to the physical act of shutting something. In this case, they're interchangeable. The fact that you can describe the ticket as open/closed makes it quite logical to say that you'll *close* the ticket, although *close out* works because it's not tangible. You couldn't, for example, *close out* a store, only *close* it. As another example, you could say:

> After I close out the week, I'll be on vacation for a month.

However, in this case, using just *close* wouldn't be appropriate, since you can't really describe the week as closed.

Comment: Ahh.. That makes sense. Thanks for such a detailed answer. 